# How to run multimple timestamps in an excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I would like to find a formula to generate a timestamp when a specific cell is updated. The difference is that I need to be able to log MULTIPLE timestamps that would not be changed if another cell is updated.

If G8 is updated, I would want a timestamp to be inputted in E8 and if G9 were updated a minute or two after, I would need a different timestamp inputted for E9 that would not change E8's timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

*The most easiest is ,, insert this formula in cell E8 and fill it down till needed.*

```
=IF(G8<>"",IF(E8="",NOW(),E8),"")
```

**N.B.**

*Now to make is static do the following:*

- Click File, then Option.
- Form the list, find FORMULA.
- Then find Enable Iterative calculation.
- Check it and set it to 1.
- Finish with Ok.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

---

*Another should be a VBA macro.*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    With Target
        If .Column = G Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                Cells(Target.Row, E).Value = Time()
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
End With
End Sub
```

---

**How it works:**

- Press Alt+F11 to get VB editor.
- Copy & Paste this code.
- Return to sheet.
- Save the WB as Macro enabled *.xlsm.

*Now as soon you enter any value in column G, this code will enter Time stamp in adjacent cell.*